# Case When statement for Dates in SQL Query

Tags: sql, db-browser-sqlite

I'm attempting to fix some of the dates I have in my SQL table. For context, I joined the two tables, "Trade Details" and "Trade Details 2" together. One of the columns in "Trade Details 2" is "START_DATE" with dates ranging back to the early 2000's in the format 2010-05-08. I'm looking to make every START_DATE before 2018-06-22 into 2018-06-22. Currently, my code is below:

```
SELECT "Trade Details 2".Portfolio, 
"Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID, 
DATE("Trade Details 2".START_DATE) as START_DATE, 
DATE(substr("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 0, 5) || '-' || substr("Trade 
Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 5,2) || '-' ||    substr("Trade Details 
2".MATURITY_DATE, 7, 9)) as MATURITY_DATE, 
"Trade Details 2".NOTIONAL1,
"Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_NPV,
"Trade Details".TERM
FROM "Trade Details 2" 
JOIN "Trade Details" 
WHERE "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID="Trade Details".FCC_ID and
("Trade Details 2".NOTIONAL1 > "0.0") and
("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE > DATE(substr('20180602', 0, 5) || '-' || 
substr('20180602', 5,2) || '-' ||    substr('20180602', 7, 9)) )
ORDER BY CONTRACT_ID asc
```

I believe that what I need is a CASE WHEN statement, where I say something like:

```
  CASE WHEN "Trade Details 2".START_DATE<2018-06-22 THEN =2018-06-22
```

However, when I tried this I got an error, and I'm guessing that some part of this line of code is wrong. However, since this is a date I don't know if a greater than/less than symbol will suffice, and I'm not sure where to put this statement, or even if this statement is totally correct. However, this is the gist of my question. This is different from other questions on here I believe because it's dealing with dates instead of simple numbers.

TLDR; Trying to turn dates prior to 2018-06-22 into 2018-06-22, but not sure how to do this

Comment: You need to include the error you are getting.

Comment: ...there's a [multi-argument `MAX(..)` function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#maxoreunc), will that not work?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse so I would write `Max("2018-06-22", "Trade Details 2".START_DATE"` somewhere? Which line would I put this code on?

Comment: Tags (sql-server, db-browser-sqlite) are a bit misleading to me. Are you working with SQL Server or with SQLite?

Comment: Instead of the `CASE` statement, just part of the columns listed in the `SELECT`.  Also, just noticed this, having tables with spaces is frowned upon.  Not least because of the need to put delimiters around them every time...

Comment: Yeah i'm working with someone elses data that i'm compiling, I didn't choose to name the tables

Comment: and i tried `Max("2018-06-22", "Trade Details 2".START_DATE")` right below `"Trade Details".TERM` so it's part of the select but it didn't work. Is there any part of the code that i'm not writing correctly for the max function

Comment: Don't forget to convert your strings to dates: `MAX(date('2018-06-22'), date("Trade Details 2".start_date))`

Answer (score 0):

First, your `CASE` statement does not look right.
It should be something like `CASE WHEN condition THEN value ELSE value END` (see [SQLite Expressions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)).

Second, because [SQLite does not have a "date" field type](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype), you're probably using a string, so you need to convert your value to a date (see [SQLite Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)):

```
date(start_date)
```

For example, considering the following simplified data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trade_details` (
    `id` INTEGER,
    `start_date` TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `trade_details` VALUES
    (1,'2018-06-01'),
    (2,'2018-06-22'),
    (3,'2018-06-23');
```

The following query should work:

```
SELECT
    id,
    start_date,
    CASE
        WHEN date(start_date) < date('2018-06-22')
        THEN '2018-06-22'
        ELSE start_date
    END AS modified_date
FROM trade_details;
```

Result:

```
+----+------------+---------------+
| id | start_date | modified_date |
+----+------------+---------------+
|  1 | 2018-06-01 | 2018-06-22    |
|  2 | 2018-06-22 | 2018-06-22    |
|  3 | 2018-06-23 | 2018-06-23    |
+----+------------+---------------+
```

You can also try and play with this SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/361ea/3/0

Comment: So would I put that stuff after my WHERE statement? So it's like `WHERE"TD2"....substr('20180622', 7, 9)) )` And then the next line is `(CASE WHEN date("Trade Details 2".START_DATE) < '2018-06-22' THEN '2018-06-22' ELSE start_date END
FROM "Trade Details 2");
ORDER BY CONTRACT_ID asc`  Is that correct?

Comment: No, it's inside after `SELECT` and before `FROM`. Use the `CASE ... END` statement as if it were a field.

Comment: Gotcha, I have this right below "Trade Details".TERM. `CASE   
  WHEN date(START_DATE) < '2018-06-22'  
  THEN '2018-06-22' 
  ELSE start_date 
 END AS modified date` It's claiming there's a syntax error near "CASE" however. I tried to put paranthesis around CASE and modified date and that didn't work either

Comment: Did you add a comma (`,`) after `"Trade Details".TERM`?

Comment: I did, and now it just deleted my table when a ran the query. It says 0 rows returned. Before I added this qualification i'm making the post about, there were 19,000 thousand rows?

Comment: `SELECT "Trade Details 2".Portfolio, 
   "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID, 
   DATE("Trade Details 2".START_DATE) as START_DATE, 
   DATE(substr("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 0, 5) || '-' || substr("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 5,2) || '-' ||    substr("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 7, 9)) as MATURITY_DATE, 
   "Trade Details 2".NOTIONAL1,
   "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_NPV,
   "Trade Details".TERM,
   MAX(date('2018-06-22'), date("Trade Details 2".start_date))` this is my updated code as a reference with the stuff after this starting at "FROM TD 2" being the same as original

Comment: If you're getting less rows, it's because of the conditions in the `JOIN` or the `WHERE` clause. Are you sure you didn't change anything below `FROM`?

Comment: Nothing changed below From. The only thing changed in the whole code is the added lin efor the max function below Term and above From

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174675/discussion-between-throway172-and-cos64).

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I thought I'd suggest some things to simply your code.

```
SELECT
  td2.Portfolio, 
  td2.CONTRACT_ID, 
  td2.NOTIONAL1,td2.CONTRACT_NPV, td.TERM,
  CASE WHEN td2.START_DATE < '2018-06-02' 
       THEN '2018-06-02' 
       ELSE td2.START_DATE AS START_DATE
FROM "Trade Details 2" td2
JOIN "Trade Details" td
WHERE td2.CONTRACT_ID=td.FCC_ID AND (td2.NOTIONAL1 > "0.0")
ORDER BY CONTRACT_ID ASC
```

1. There is no need to convert the text dates to date values since the date format chosen will allow a simple string sort.
2. An 'alias' can be chosen for your tables, say 'td' and 'td2'. Doing this will clear up a lot of the clutter.

Hope this is useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out. See below.

```
  select *
  ,case when  2015 >= year(startdate) and 2015 <= year(enddate) then 'yes' end as '2015'
  ,case when  2016 >= year(startdate) and 2016 <= year(enddate) then 'yes' end as '2016'
  ,case when  2017 >= year(startdate) and 2017 <= year(enddate) then 'yes' end as '2017'
  ,case when  2018 >= year(startdate) and 2018 <= year(enddate) then 'yes' end as '2018'
  ,case when  2019 >= year(startdate) and 2019 <= year(enddate) then 'yes' end as '2019'
  ,case when  2020 >= year(startdate) and 2020 <= year(enddate) then 'yes' end as '2020'
  ,case when  2021 >= year(startdate) and 2021 <= year(enddate) then 'yes' end as '2021'
  ,case when  2022 >= year(startdate) and 2022 <= year(enddate) then 'yes' end as '2022'
  from #Have
  order by ID
```